# java relative path to ressource in playframework project

Tags: java, playframework

I have a microsoft access database file mdb. At the moment I have a absolute path defined. Is there a way to set an relative path to the mdb file?

I use it in my dto / dao. Its a playframework project

Code looks like this:

```
 String msAccDB = "C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/dataposcrmbackend/resources/DataposCO.mdb";
 String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + msAccDB;
```

I tried this:

```
String msAccDB = "../../resources/DataposCO.mdb";
```

But I got errors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dataposcrmbackend` is your project?

Comment: yes thats the root folder name of my project

Comment: Works fine will you post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go back using`../../` in this problem, you only need to use the path that you will access.

The relative path is:

```
String msAccDB = "resources/DataposCO.mdb"
```